# Finding and Replacing multiple strings in an XML file

Tags: xml, batch-file

I want to find and replace multiple strings in single or multiple XML files all at once. I have tried parameterizing the xml input files and passing variables for finding and replacing matching patterns. Using a `for` loop is time-consuming, as it is a nested `for` loop. can we write using "if exists"

The code is as follows:
-- for find/replace script

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "search="%~1""
set "replace="%~2""
set "textfile=%3"

  for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
        >>"%textFile%" echo(!line!
        endlocal
    )
```

-- input variables

```
 @echo off

set source=<SRCpath>"
set target=<TGTpath>

xcopy /Y %<SRC>%\* %<TGT>%\*
dir /s /b "%TGT%\*.xml" > filenames.txt -- for multi i/p files
set filename="<i/p>\filenames.txt"
set paramfile="<variable values path>\parm.txt"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('type "%filenames%"') DO (
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=" %%j in ('type "%parm%"') do call <Find/Replace script.bat> %%j %%k %%i 
)
```

Comment: Is this the entire code? There's no way this will work by itself. (Also, `for` loops are perfectly capable of simply taking a file as input; no need for the `type` commands whatsoever.)

Comment: thats not the full code, the logic i implemented

Comment: actually its working fine but the issue came is performance

Comment: If I copied and pasted everything you have provided, and _only_ what you have provided, it wouldn't work for me. Please add enough code so that your example is [minimal, complete, and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: also would like to know that CAN WE SPECIFY A PARTICULAR RANGE to  perform find/replace?? Ex- if i have 100 lines in a xml file, i would like to replace a particular string if it comes lines between 20 and 60. can we implement this..Thanks in advance

Comment: [JREPL.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) should be able to do that. You could also store the desired lines in a temp file, edit them, and then recreate your original file if that's acceptable.

Comment: is this a kind of pre defined tool coz if it is i am not supposed to use any.. could u please help me in letting me know that can we specify a range and if yes how can we implement that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excuse me. If I correctly understood your *comments*, your problem is *not* "Finding and Replacing multiple strings in an XML file" (because you already have a code that solve that problem), but do that *in an efficient way*! You should be very clear in your requests, otherwise you will get answers that don't solve your problem (wasting the time of the people that try to help you).

Your code have several constructs that are particularly slow. The code below uses your same method to "finding and replacing strings", but using more efficient constructs.

```
@echo off

set source=<SRCpath>"
set target=<TGTpath>

xcopy /Y %<SRC>%\* %<TGT>%\*
set paramfile="<variable values path>\parm.txt"
rem Process all .xml files
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /s /b "%TGT%\*.xml"') do (
   rem Process all lines in each file
   (for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("%%f") do (
      set "line=%%i"
      setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
      rem Replace all strings in paramfile
      for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2" %%j in ("%parm%") do (
         set "line=!line:%%j=%%k!"
      )
      echo(!line!
      endlocal
   )) > tempfile.tmp
   move /Y tempfile.tmp "%%f"
)
```

Note that I used *your exact same code* and that I just rearranged it in order to improve the performance. This means that you must fix any missing value, error, etc. that your code may have.

**EDIT**: *Range of lines for replacements added*

The modification below allows to specify a particular range of lines to perform find/replace; the optional range is given in the parameters of the Batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "ifInRange="
set "endIf="
rem If two parameters are given, they specify the desired range of lines for replacements
if "%~2" equ "" goto begin

set "ifInRange=if %%h geq %1 if %%h leq %2 ("
set "endIf=)"

:begin

set source=<SRCpath>"
set target=<TGTpath>

xcopy /Y %<SRC>%\* %<TGT>%\*
set paramfile="<variable values path>\parm.txt"
rem Process all .xml files
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /s /b "%TGT%\*.xml"') do (
   rem Process all lines in each file
   (for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%h in ('findstr /N "^" "%%f"') do (
      set "line=%%i"
      setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
      rem Check if a line range was given
      %ifInRange%
         rem Replace all strings in paramfile
         for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2" %%j in ("%parm%") do (
            set "line=!line:%%j=%%k!"
         )
      %endIf%
      echo(!line!
      endlocal
   )) > tempfile.tmp
   move /Y tempfile.tmp "%%f"
)
```

**EDIT #2**: *Reply to comment*

You may specify the range of lines as parameters of the Batch file. For example, to process lines from 20 to 60:

```
batchFileName.bat 20 60
```

However, if the range of lines is always the same, you may simplify the code this way:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set source=<SRCpath>"
set target=<TGTpath>

xcopy /Y %<SRC>%\* %<TGT>%\*
set paramfile="<variable values path>\parm.txt"
rem Process all .xml files
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /s /b "%TGT%\*.xml"') do (
   rem Process all lines in each file
   (for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%h in ('findstr /N "^" "%%f"') do (
      set "line=%%i"
      setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
      rem Check if the line is in range
      if %%h geq 20 if %%h leq 60 (
         rem Replace all strings in paramfile
         for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2" %%j in ("%parm%") do (
            set "line=!line:%%j=%%k!"
         )
      )
      echo(!line!
      endlocal
   )) > tempfile.tmp
   move /Y tempfile.tmp "%%f"
)
```

Comment: Hi aacini.. It worked fine for me.. i can specify range in hardcoded way but lik u said how can we provide the range as parameters in batch file?? Is it like in the parameter file(find/replace param file) i have to give those parameters also?? Thanks you so much for the help

Comment: and thanks for the suggestions making me better in the way to ask appropriate questions

Comment: See the second edit in my answer. I'll appreciate it if you may post the timing results of your original code vs. my modification...

Comment: Previously It took 20 min for a 1MB file  and now the same is done in just less than a minute

Comment: Thanks! This type of results encourage us to keep posting these solutions. `:-)`

Comment: Hi aacini here i am trying to pass parameters which includes spaces and i kept them in double quotes and i have changed delims to SPACE but it is not replacing the instances

Comment: could you please help me on the same Rest all of the script is working fine except when i try to pass parameters as mentioned in my above comments...Thanks in advance

Comment: Search for ["parameters with spaces"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+parameters+with+spaces) in "batch-file" questions. If no one of the answers solve your problem, post a new question with a _detailed_ description.

Comment: Hi i went through that but i dont know what wrong i am code.. I tried to pass parameters using '~' and ""(double qoutes) but i am still unable to pass parameters with spaces

Comment: Please, note that your problem with parameters with spaces have NO relation with _this_ topic ("Finding and Replacing multiple strings in an XML file")! Post a new question and include your complete code and a copy of the way the parameters are passed and the output generated...

Answer (score 0):

It's generally more graceful to parse and manipulate XML as XML, rather than as text to scrape and hack.  That way you aren't so dependent upon anticipating the formatting of the files you're manipulating -- line breaks in the middle of tags, for example.  To that end, I suggest that you employ Windows Scripting Host and use the `Microsoft.XMLDOM` COM object to manipulate the XML DOM.

The following batch + JScript hybrid examples should be saved with a .bat extension.

If it's attributes you're editing:

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

set "attribute=SERVERNAME"
set "new_value=This works."

for %%I in (*.xml) do (
    rem // invoke JScript for each XML file
    cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%%~I" "%attribute%" "%new_value%"
)

goto :EOF
@end // end batch / begin JScript chimera

var DOM = WSH.CreateObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM'),
    args = { file: WSH.Arguments(0), attr: WSH.Arguments(1), val: WSH.Arguments(2) };

DOM.load(args.file);
DOM.async = false;
DOM.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');

if (DOM.parseError.errorCode) {
    var e = DOM.parseError;
    WSH.StdErr.WriteLine('Error in ' + args.file + ' line ' + e.line + ' char '
        + e.linepos + ':\n' + e.reason + '\n' + e.srcText);
    WSH.Quit(1);
}

for (var d = DOM.selectNodes('//*[@' + args.attr + ']'), i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
    d[i].setAttribute(args.attr, args.val);

DOM.save(args.file);
```

If you're editing text nodes:

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

set "search=SERVERNAME"
set "replace=This works."

for %%I in (*.xml) do (
    rem // invoke JScript for each XML file
    cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%%~I" "%search%" "%replace%"
)

goto :EOF
@end // end batch / begin JScript chimera

var DOM = WSH.CreateObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM'),
    args = { file: WSH.Arguments(0), search: WSH.Arguments(1), repl: WSH.Arguments(2) },
    XPath = "//text()[contains(.,'" + args.search + "')]";

DOM.load(args.file);
DOM.async = false;
DOM.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');

if (DOM.parseError.errorCode) {
    var e = DOM.parseError;
    WSH.StdErr.WriteLine('Error in ' + args.file + ' line ' + e.line + ' char '
        + e.linepos + ':\n' + e.reason + '\n' + e.srcText);
    WSH.Quit(1);
}

for (var d = DOM.selectNodes(XPath), i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
    d[i].nodeValue = args.repl;

DOM.save(args.file);
```

And if you want to limit the modifications made, just use a more specific XPath selector.  For example, instead of `//text()` you could use `/rootname/parent/child/text()` with the names of the tags drilling down the hierarchy to the text node you wish to modify.