# how to edit XML files in batch / python

Tags: python, xml, batch-file, vbscript, fetch

### I'm trying to edit `xml` files in a batch / python script

**this is my xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<task name="analyse">
   <taskInfo taskId="21a09311-ade3-4e9a-af21-d13be8b7ba45" runAt="2015-05-20 13:48:50" runTime="5 minutes, 53 seconds">
      <project name="13955 - HMI Volvo Truck PA15" number="e20d51c0-71dc-4572-8f9b-4c150bf35222" />
      <language lcid="1031" name="German (Germany)" />
      <tm name="ENG-DEU_en-GB_de-DE.sdltm" />
      <settings reportInternalFuzzyLeverage="yes" reportLockedSegments="no" reportCrossFileRepetitions="yes" minimumMatchScore="70" searchMode="bestWins" missingFormattingPenalty="1" differentFormattingPenalty="1" multipleTranslationsPenalty="1" autoLocalizationPenalty="0" textReplacementPenalty="0" />
   </taskInfo>
   <file name="VT MAIN TRACK_PA15_Default_DE-DE_20150520_102527.xlf.sdlxliff" guid="111f9ba6-82f6-45fb-ac49-8bf6cf57c169">
      <analyse>
         <perfect segments="0" words="0" characters="0" placeables="0" tags="0" />
         <inContextExact segments="60" words="55" characters="755" placeables="3" tags="0" />
         ' Replace the Value word="55" with "0"
         <exact segments="114" words="334" characters="1687" placeables="14" tags="3" />
         <locked segments="0" words="0" characters="0" placeables="0" tags="0" />
         <crossFileRepeated segments="2" words="20" characters="0" placeables="0" tags="0" />
         'Cut the value words="20" replace with 0
         <repeated segments="17" words="34" characters="293" placeables="2" tags="0" />
         'add the value to current value 20 to 34  so the new value is words="54"
         <total segments="449" words="1462" characters="7630" placeables="66" tags="24" />
         <new segments="126" words="434" characters="2384" placeables="18" tags="5" />
         <fuzzy min="75" max="84" segments="25" words="108" characters="528" placeables="6" tags="3" />
         <fuzzy min="85" max="94" segments="23" words="92" characters="454" placeables="7" tags="4" />
         <fuzzy min="95" max="99" segments="77" words="260" characters="1318" placeables="13" tags="6" />
         <internalFuzzy min="75" max="84" segments="3" words="16" characters="100" placeables="2" tags="2" />
         <internalFuzzy min="85" max="94" segments="4" words="25" characters="111" placeables="1" tags="1" />
         <internalFuzzy min="95" max="99" segments="0" words="0" characters="0" placeables="0" tags="0" />
      </analyse>
   </file>
   <file name="VT MAIN TRACK_PA15_Default_DE-DE_20150523_254796.xlf.sdlxliff" guid="111f9ba6-82f6-45fb-ac49-8bf6cf57c169">
      <analyse>
         <perfect segments="0" words="0" characters="0" placeables="0" tags="0" />
         <inContextExact segments="60" words="67" characters="755" placeables="3" tags="0" />
         ' Replace the Value word="67" with "0"
         <exact segments="114" words="334" characters="1687" placeables="14" tags="3" />
         <locked segments="0" words="0" characters="0" placeables="0" tags="0" />
         <crossFileRepeated segments="2" words="35" characters="0" placeables="0" tags="0" />
         'Cut the value words="35" replace with 0
         <repeated segments="17" words="54" characters="293" placeables="2" tags="0" />
         'add the value to current value 35 to 54  so the new value is words="89"
         <total segments="449" words="1462" characters="7630" placeables="66" tags="24" />
         <new segments="126" words="434" characters="2384" placeables="18" tags="5" />
         <fuzzy min="75" max="84" segments="25" words="108" characters="528" placeables="6" tags="3" />
         <fuzzy min="85" max="94" segments="23" words="92" characters="454" placeables="7" tags="4" />
         <fuzzy min="95" max="99" segments="77" words="260" characters="1318" placeables="13" tags="6" />
         <internalFuzzy min="75" max="84" segments="3" words="16" characters="100" placeables="2" tags="2" />
         <internalFuzzy min="85" max="94" segments="4" words="25" characters="111" placeables="1" tags="1" />
         <internalFuzzy min="95" max="99" segments="0" words="0" characters="0" placeables="0" tags="0" />
      </analyse>
   </file>
   <batchTotal>
      <analyse>
         <perfect segments="0" words="0" characters="0" placeables="0" tags="0" />
         <inContextExact segments="60" words="139" characters="755" placeables="3" tags="0" />
         <exact segments="114" words="334" characters="1687" placeables="14" tags="3" />
         <locked segments="0" words="0" characters="0" placeables="0" tags="0" />
         <crossFileRepeated segments="0" words="0" characters="0" placeables="0" tags="0" />
         <repeated segments="17" words="54" characters="293" placeables="2" tags="0" />
         <total segments="449" words="1462" characters="7630" placeables="66" tags="24" />
         <new segments="126" words="434" characters="2384" placeables="18" tags="5" />
         <fuzzy min="75" max="84" segments="25" words="108" characters="528" placeables="6" tags="3" />
         <fuzzy min="85" max="94" segments="23" words="92" characters="454" placeables="7" tags="4" />
         <fuzzy min="95" max="99" segments="77" words="260" characters="1318" placeables="13" tags="6" />
         <internalFuzzy min="75" max="84" segments="3" words="16" characters="100" placeables="2" tags="2" />
         <internalFuzzy min="85" max="94" segments="4" words="25" characters="111" placeables="1" tags="1" />
         <internalFuzzy min="95" max="99" segments="0" words="0" characters="0" placeables="0" tags="0" />
      </analyse>
   </batchTotal>
</task>
```

general notes:

- the `<task>` is the root element  (end element  `</task>`)
- the important here is to modify a few tags in a section called file `<file>` and endtag `</file>`
- there can be X occurrences of `<file>*</file>`

### What i need,

for each `<file>` element, i would like to:

- In `<inContextExact>`, Set the value of the attribute `words` with 0

  `<inContextExact ... words="55" ... />`  **=>** `<inContextExact ... words="0" ... />`
- In `<crossFileRepeated>`, Set the value of the attribute `words` with 0

  `<crossFileRepeated ... words="20" ... />` **=>**  `<crossFileRepeated ... words="0" ... />`
- In `<total>`, Set the value of the  `words` attribute to be calculated by my own logic

  `<total ... words="1462" ... />`  **=>** `<total ... words="??" ... />`

### I could really appreciate an example of processing XML files in batch / python

Comment: Have you tried searching the web? I'm sure you'll find lots of examples.

Comment: Yeah some but I guess someone here could help me.

Comment: Write a program which does what you want. If you fail, come back and tell us about what you did and what does not work.

Comment: @DanielElmnas, saw you tagged this question `python`. is `python` solution is acceptable?

Comment: Well sure if you can.

Comment: @DanielElmnas; on it.

Comment: @DanielElmnas [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30123871/1683264) for an example of manipulating XML with a batch + JScript hybrid script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Let's utilize python!

it's extremely easy to do that in python. and since you said it's ok to make a solution in python, check the script below.

here's how you can **iterate over a directory** contains `xml` files and **process them as requested** in python while saving the file changes.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import os

def edit_xml_file(data):
    e = ElementTree.fromstring(data)

    for file_element in e.findall('file'):

        analyse_element = file_element.find('analyse')

        in_context_exact_element = analyse_element.find('inContextExact')
        in_context_exact_words = int(in_context_exact_element.get('words'))
        in_context_exact_element.set('words', '0')

        cross_file_repeated_element = analyse_element.find('crossFileRepeated')
        cross_file_repeated_words = int(cross_file_repeated_element.get('words'))
        cross_file_repeated_element.set('words', '0')

        total_element = analyse_element.find('total')
        total_element.set('words', str(in_context_exact_words + cross_file_repeated_words))

    xmlstr = ElementTree.tostring(e)
    return xmlstr


def main():

    source_directory = 'xmlfiles'

    for filename in os.listdir(source_directory):

        if not filename.endswith('.xml'):
            continue

        xml_file_path = os.path.join(source_directory, filename)
        with open(xml_file_path, 'r+b') as f:
            data = f.read()
            fixed_data = edit_xml_file(data)
            f.seek(0)
            f.write(fixed_data)
            f.truncate()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

in this solution, iv'e used [the built in `ElementTree` utility](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Comment: Haha awesome,
how do I use the python script? xD

Comment: The script says cannot find any XMLfiles, I installed python run cmd, navigate to C:/python34/test.py also I have got xml files in the same location

Comment: I get C:\Python34>lol.py
  File "C:\Python34\lol.py", line 28
    source_directory ="C:\test"
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

C:\Python34>
I also tried "C:\test\*.xls" and
"C:\test\"

Comment: I need at least +20 rep to be able to talk in the room.

Comment: I still can't talk to you? Hmm strange.. I'll try to relogon

Comment: Ok I download it now what about my mypath how do you write it?
the folder with xml files are located  C:\test\

Comment: `source_directory = r'C:\test\'`

Comment: IndentationError: unexpected indent

C:\Python27>python.exe C:\Python27\lol.py
  File "C:\Python27\lol.py", line 31
    source_directory = r'C:\test\'
                   ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

C:\Python27>

Comment: it means you need to add spaces, like this: `____source_directory = r'C:\test\'` **(_ = space)**

Answer (score 0):

### Necessary tools

Here are the necessary tools you will need to create a script in `Excel VBA` or `VBscript`:

**Looping text files in a directory:** [link](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dir.php)

**Reading text files:** [link](http://www.analystcave.com/vba-read-file-vba/)

**Writing text files:** [link](http://www.analystcave.com/vba-write-file-vba/)

**Replacing using RegExp:** [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx)

Example Regex to get you going:

```
<exact segments="114" words="334" characters="1687" placeables="14" tags="3" />
->
<exact segments="114" words="0" characters="1687" placeables="14" tags="3" />
```

Use this regex:
`(words="[0-9]+?")` or `words="([0-9]+?)"` even better

Below an example of processing a single row:

```
Dim re as RegExp
set re = new RegExp
re.Pattern = "words="([0-9]+?)"
newTextRow = re.Replace(textRow, 0) 'Replace word value with 0
```

### The approach

1. Loop through your XML files using the `Dir` function
2. Read the contents of the file using the link above on how to read text files in VBA
3. Loop through all rows and use the `RegExp` function to replace the necessary word params
4. Save the output back to the XML file using the link above on how to write text files in VBA

Comment: hmm I dont really get it what to do with it?

Comment: Just create a VBA/VBscript and follow the approach using the resources I posted above

Comment: Well  I should actually need more help......
Have you even opened the links you did google for me?.

Comment: Of course I opened them. 2 of them are my posts. More help...You mean basically write the script for you ;>?

Comment: I trying now but gonna take years haaha but Indeed yeah I should need your pro help lol. Thank you so far.