# Batch Program questions

Tags: xml, batch-file

I have a batch program that reads an xml file.  The program for reading the xml works fine.  Here is my problem.

I have certain nodes located within my xml that I need to check and update using batch.  I am thinking a loop command would work but can not wrap my head around it.  Here is a sample of the xml nodes needed to check and update:

```
 <carType>Truck</carType>
 <carColor>Blue</carColor>
 <carLocal>NES</carLocal>
```

Lets say the xml has up to a hundred of these nodes.   I am able to pull the "Truck" "Blue" and "NES" from the batch file. What I need to do is update the  node with these variables:
NES
BOR
BAK

I need to also check if  is "Truck" Do not put "BOR" or "BAK" in that field.

Here is the batch code:

```
 REM Finds the Parent Nodes for /F "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%i in ('findstr "<carType" AST.txt') do echo %%i >>tags.txt 

REM Continue with this loop for other conditions within XML sheet

REM START THE RANDOM Trucks BOR or BAK
:Pname4 
Set thisa=%Random% 
If /i %thisa% GTR 3 goto 
Pname4 If /i %thisa% LSS 1 goto Pname4 
goto playername 
:playername 
If %thisa% == 1 set pnameaa=Truck 
If %thisa% == 2 set pnameaa=BOR
If %thisa% == 3 set pnameaa=BAK 
goto xmlstuff 
:xmlstuff echo(^<carType^>%pnameaa%^</carType^> 
echo(^<carColor^>%pnameaa%^</carColor^>
echo(^<carLocal^>%rpnameaa%^</carLocal^> 
)>my.xml
```

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Please show what you have so far.

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30123871/1683264) for ideas.  If no one else has answered by tomorrow, if I get a chance I'll help you out.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do, the structure of your XML file, what values go where, and so on.  In your example batch code, you appear to be setting the `<carType>` and `<carColor>` nodes to the same value, then `<carLocal>` to a value that is never set anywhere (not to mention lazy pasting of the code leaving incorrect line breaks in a couple of places).  You also state that the random values should be either **NES**, **BOR**, or **BAK**; but your code sets the random values to either **Truck**, **BOR**, or **BAK**.  Are you sure you have fully decided upon what it is that you want to happen?  Don't be lazy.  You can do better than this.

Be that as it may, I said I would post an answer, and so I shall.

It's generally more graceful to parse and manipulate XML *as* XML, rather than as text to scrape and hack. That way you aren't so dependent upon anticipating the formatting of the XML you're manipulating (whether it's beautified, uglified, minified, whatever). To that end, I suggest that you employ Windows Scripting Host and use the `Microsoft.XMLDOM` COM object to manipulate the XML DOM.

I'm taking a wild guess here, guessing that the only value you really want to change is `<carLocal>`, but where `<carType>` is Truck, `<carLocal>` shouldn't accept values of either `BOR` or `BAK`.  This should also write every `<carType>` text node value to `tags.txt`.

The following XML structure is assumed:

```xml
<xmlroot>
    <car>
        <carType>Truck</carType>
        <carColor>Blue</carColor>
        <carLocal>NES</carLocal>
    </car>
    <car>
        <carType>Sedan</carType>
        <carColor>Yellow</carColor>
        <carLocal>BOR</carLocal>
    </car>
    <car>
        <carType>Blimp</carType>
        <carColor>Silver</carColor>
        <carLocal>BOR</carLocal>
    </car>
</xmlroot>
```

The following batch + JScript hybrid example should be saved with a .bat extension.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

rem // Randomly generate either NES, BOR, or BAK
set /a idx = %RANDOM% * 3 / 32768 + 1
for /f "tokens=%idx%" %%I in ("NES BOR BAK") do set "repl=%%I"

rem // invoke JScript to update XML
cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "test.xml" "%repl%" >tags.txt

goto :EOF
@end // end batch / begin JScript chimera

var DOM = WSH.CreateObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM'),
    args = { file: WSH.Arguments(0), repl: WSH.Arguments(1) };

DOM.load(args.file);
DOM.async = false;
DOM.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');

if (DOM.parseError.errorCode) {
    var e = DOM.parseError;
    WSH.StdErr.WriteLine('Error in ' + args.file + ' line ' + e.line + ' char '
        + e.linepos + ':\n' + e.reason + '\n' + e.srcText);
    WSH.Quit(1);
}

for (var d = DOM.selectNodes('//car'), i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    var car = {
        type: d[i].getElementsByTagName('carType')[0].childNodes[0],
        color: d[i].getElementsByTagName('carColor')[0].childNodes[0],
        local: d[i].getElementsByTagName('carLocal')[0].childNodes[0]
    };

    if (car.type.nodeValue != 'Truck' || !/(BOR|BAK)/.test(args.repl))
        car.local.nodeValue = args.repl;
    WSH.Echo(car.type.nodeValue);
}

DOM.save(args.file);
```

Hopefully this should get you started.  If you have questions about what a particular command does, I'll be happy to answer.  But I don't intend to rewrite any of this code to your specifications.  I'll leave that to you.