# Reading Current Directory from XML file

Tags: xml, batch-file

I have an XML File I use for my parameters file (e.g. stating paths to action things from, depending on the server a batch file is run from, so I can use the same batch file everywhere)
For example I have the XML File name "Global.DeployParameters.xml" which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parameters>
    <deploy>
        <SoftwareToInstallPaths>
            <softwarepath>
                C:\Software
            </softwarepath>
```

and in my batch file I have this to find it and set the variable %softwarepath% to read "C:\Software"

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%n in ('findstr /n /i /c:"<softwarepath>" "Global.DeployParameters.xml"') do (
for /f "tokens=*" %%l in ('type "Global.DeployParameters.xml" ^| more +%%n') do set "softwarepath=%%l" & goto endLoop
)
:endLoop
```

and in the same batch file, if I were to do:

```
COPY "C:\test\*.*" "%softwarepath%"
```

If would work fine and copy the file in there to the location that the batch file is, however if I changed the XML File to read

```
<softwarepath>
    %~dp0..
</softwarepath>
```

to say, copy the content of "C:\test\" to a folder level above where the "Batch file Current Path" is, instead it would make a file the same named "%~dp0" where the batch file is located but If I hard copy in the batch file "%~dp0.." it will work.

I can't hard code this as it's a different location on each server so need to reading from the XML file for that particular server. How can I get it to read the XML text as a command and not the literal text?

Comment: do not understand.. `%~dp0` is always accessible from the script and you don't need to read it from xml.

Comment: I know it does, on some servers the Drive I need to copy files to are no where the batch file can be situated. but on some servers it needs to be like that and there are multiple ones to do it for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```js
do set "softwarepath=%%l"
```

... you should

```js
do call set "softwarepath=%%l"
```

to expand `%%l` another level of depth.

---

I'd also recommend parsing your XML as XML, rather than tokenizing and scraping it as text.  If you parse it as XML, then the success of your script won't be so dependent upon whether the XML is beautified, uglified, minified, whatever.  I know this is more code, but it's also more resistant to changes in your XML file without noticeably giving up any efficiency.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

set "XMLfile=test.xml"
set "node=softwarepath"

for /f "delims=" %%I in (
    'cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%XMLfile%" "%node%"'
) do call set "%%I"

echo Software path: %softwarepath%..

rem // put your copy statement and whatever else you wish here.

goto :EOF
@end // end batch / begin JScript chimera

String.prototype.trim = function() { return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); }

var DOM = WSH.CreateObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM'),
    args = { file: WSH.Arguments(0), node: WSH.Arguments(1) },
    XPath = "//" + args.node + "/text()";

DOM.load(args.file);
DOM.async = false;
DOM.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');

if (DOM.parseError.errorCode) {
    var e = DOM.parseError;
    WSH.StdErr.WriteLine('Error in ' + args.file + ' line ' + e.line + ' char '
        + e.linepos + ':\n' + e.reason + '\n' + e.srcText);
    WSH.Quit(1);
}

for (var d = DOM.selectNodes(XPath), i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
    WSH.Echo(args.node + '=' + d[i].nodeValue.trim());
```

As a bonus, only minor changes would be needed if you wanted to script not only reading the XML, but [modifying and saving it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30123871/1683264) as well.

Comment: Thanks, 
do call set "softwarepath=%%l" 

is exactly what I needed!