# Update XML attribute values by reading the parameters from Batch file

Tags: xml, batch-file

I have an XML file with the below syntax:

```
"<"example:param default="admin" var="User">
```

I need to write a batch script which takes the input (username) from CMD and then updates the default attribute value with the input provided by the user.

Below is my sample batch file for reading values form CMD:

```
@SET /P pat=Enter Username:

@ECHO Path Entered:%pat%
```

Now how do I update the XML with `%pat%` value.
There will be only one attribute with name `User` in the XML file.

This is my first day in batch scripting.
Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: is that xml file contain only one line?

Comment: Please use search before asking, [there are lots](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+edit+xml) of examples of editing xml in batch files.

Comment: Thank you very much..I got it

Comment: I was going to suggest [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30123871/1683264).  If you're tokenizing and parsing your XML as flat text, you shouldn't be.

Comment: @Sravan, if you got the solution, please provide it as an answer and accept it; so the question does no longer remain open in the SO database...