# How do I successfully replace text with batch in XML

Tags: xml, string, batch-file, replace

I have tried to replace in my XML page a string using batch but I can't succeed to replace it fully.

I have this batch code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set _search=logLevel^="3"
set _replace=logLevel^="4"

for /F "delims=*" %%a in (config.xml) do (
set line=%%a
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
>> newconfig.xml echo(!line:%_search%=%_replace%!
endlocal
)
echo "done"
pause >nul
```

And I am trying to modify this line of code in my XML:

```
<logger logfileDirectory="path/to/logging/" logLevel="3"/>
```

...from `logLevel="3"` to `logLevel="4"`:

```
<logger logfileDirectory="path/to/logging/" logLevel="4"/>
```

But it always returns me:

```
<logger logfileDirectory="path/to/logging/" "3"=logLevel="4"="3"/>
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30123871/1683264 .  In the first script, `set "attribute=logLevel"` and `set "new_value=4"`, and that should pretty much work for your situation without any other editing I think.

Comment: The direct answer to your question is that the equal signs in your `%_search%` and `%_replace%` variable values are breaking the substring substitution.

Comment: Yes, @rojo is right; your escaping `^=` has actually no effect on the replacement (I guess even double-escaping `^^=` wouldn't change anything, although I can't test it right now); you might therefore exchange all `=` by an elsewhere unused character, do the `logLevel` replacement, and then exchange back the `=`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [replacer.bat](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/master/hybrids/jscript/replacer.bat)

```
call replacer.bat "e?C:\content.txt" "<logger logfileDirectory=\u0022path/to/logging/\u0022 logLevel=\u00223\u0022/>" "<logger logfileDirectory=\u0022path/to/logging/\u0022 logLevel=\u00224\u0022/>"
```

you can check also [FindRepl](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697) and [JRepl](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) which are more sophisticated tools

Comment: This does exactly what i need, thank you. Mark as solved.

Answer (score 0):

input:

```
<logger logfileDirectory="path/to/logging/" logLevel="1"/>
<logger logfileDirectory="path/to/logging/" logLevel="2"/>
<logger logfileDirectory="path/to/logging/" logLevel="3"/>
<logger logfileDirectory="path/to/logging/" logLevel="4"/>
<logger logfileDirectory="path/to/logging/" logLevel="5"/>
```

script:

```dos
@echo off

if exist %TEMP%\_file.tmp del %TEMP%\_file.tmp

rem creating env testing
(
    for /l %%i in (1,1,5) do (
        echo ^<logger logfileDirectory="path/to/logging/" logLevel="%%i"/^>
    )
)>%TEMP%\_file.tmp


setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "_search="3""
set "_replace="4""

for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims==" %%a in (%TEMP%\_file.tmp) do (

    set a=%%a
    set b=%%b
    set c=%%c
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!a!=!b!=!c:%_search%=%_replace%!
    endlocal
)
echo "done"
exit /b 0
```

output

```dos
<logger logfileDirectory="path/to/logging/" logLevel="1"/>
<logger logfileDirectory="path/to/logging/" logLevel="2"/>
<logger logfileDirectory="path/to/logging/" logLevel="4"/>
<logger logfileDirectory="path/to/logging/" logLevel="4"/>
<logger logfileDirectory="path/to/logging/" logLevel="5"/>
"done"
```

Comment: Hi, this code is the only one so far changing but, it deletes my whole 2000 Lines to add this 5 logger lines, there in my script is only 1 logger line and i need to change the loglevel of it sometimes from 3 to 4 and back from 4 to 3, any way of doing that? Thanks.