# Replacing text line in Xml file with string and variable using batch

Tags: xml, string, batch-file

So the challenge I'm faced with is the following.

I receive an xml file that looks like:

```
<Person>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Doe</LastName>
    <MiddleName>x</MiddleName>
    <Credential>
      <Name>John Doe</Name>
      <GUID>xxxxxx </GUID>
      <ExpirationDateTime>5/31/2017 10:59:00 PM</ExpirationDateTime>
      <ObjectID>5051</ObjectID>
    </Credential>
  </Person>
```

Now my goal is to change the expiration date field to the current date at 1 AM.

This is what I have so far.
I can get rid of the field and I can echo the date time in the format I need it in. but I can't think of a way to reinsert the new expiry date in the same place

```
@echo off

cd %~dp0
copy Original.xml In.xml

for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%a/%%b/%%c)
set mytime=01:00:00 AM

echo %mydate% %mytime% 

findstr /v "ExpirationDateTime" In.xml>Out.xml

PAUSE
```

I was thinking about recreating the field and finding  and inserting it there. but batch files are not my area of expertise. What command would help accomplish this task?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I successfully replace text with batch in XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719582/how-do-i-successfully-replace-text-with-batch-in-xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that may work for you. Not super elegant because it uses a temporary file to store a value that eventually gets assigned to an environment variable, but at least the batch file cleans up after itself. It creates a "result.xml" file as its output.
Note that I had to change the date format in my batch file because my Locale is different than yours, but just reset it to what you had and it should work.

```
@Echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=- " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%a-%%b-%%c)
set mytime=01:00:00 AM
set isFound=
if exist result.xml del result.xml
for /F "delims=" %%i in (test.xml) do (
  echo "%%i" | find /c "ExpirationDateTime" > tst.tst
  set /p isFound=<tst.tst
  del tst.tst
  if "!isFound!"=="1" (
    echo       ^<ExpirationDateTime^>%mydate% %mytime%^</ExpirationDateTime^> >> result.xml
  ) ELSE (
    echo %%i >> result.xml
  )
)
set isFound=
```